# Defining a function with another function

Tags: python, python-3.x

Could someone help explain what's going on here? I don't understand what is going on in the third part, and why the result is 9. Thank you!

```
>>> def square(x):
        return x ** 2

>>> def f(x):
        return x * x

>>> def try_f(f):
        return f(3)

>>> try_f(square)
9
```

Comment: The `def f...` function definition is confusing things. It doesn't have anything to do with what's going on here. If you remove that, does it make more sense to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling `try_f(square)` you are passing the `square` function to `try_f`.
Inside `try_f` you named the first argument `f`: it will have nothing to do with the `f()` function defined below. This is now a local variable to the current scope of `try_f`.

As a better example, take this:

```
def square(x):
    return x * x

def double(x):
    return x * 2

def try_f(func):
    return func(4)

>>> try_f(square)
16
>>> try_f(double)
8
```

Answer (score 0):

The third function has a function as a parameter so when called it runs the parameter-function with a 3 as a paramater.

try_f(f=square) resolves as square(x=3) which resolves as x*x= 3*3 = 9

Comment: Clearer to say `x ** 2` = `3 ** 2` = `9`? Just my thoughts... because we're referring to the first function.

Answer (score 0):

you call square function by parameter passing from try_f function and pass 3 as argument to it. You can add print  to observe which function is called.

Defining f function doesn't take affect try_f behavour